# Logo in the middle of navigation bar

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I have come across a few examples while searching SO but to me - as a beginner - it is not very clear what the best practices are when it comes to implementing this.

I want to have the logo in the middle of my navigation bar with 2 links to centered left of the image and 2 centered right so that my 4 links so that the center of the logo aligns with the 4 links horizontaly.

For your reference:
http://jsfiddle.net/8fc0e632/

```
HTML:

<body>
<nav class="menubar">
    <div id= "navmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Info.html">Over ons</a></Li>
            <Li><a href="Menu.html">Menukaart</a></Li>
            <li><a class="logo" href="Info.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/WwCbbpG.jpg" alt="First8 Logo"></a></li>
            <Li><a href="Ontbijtmanden.html">Ontbijtmanden</a></Li>
            <Li><a href="Contact.html">Contacteer ons</a></Li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
CSS:

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,800italic);

.body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.menubar {
    background: rgb(228, 6, 19);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #999;
    font-family: inherit;
}

.menubar ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menubar ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.menubar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans"
}

.logo img {
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  display: block;
  width:220px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it like this, you will have to set the li width, because menu items are not the same length.

CSS:

```
.menubar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 220px;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and here's your updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fc0e632/1/)

But in my opinion the best what you can do is to use [Bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)

//Oh and you should always use `<li></li>` not `<Li></Li>` and definitely not `<li></Li>`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can center img elements with by adding margin: 0 auto; to the property you want to center(in your case .logo img)
otherwise i would go with a margin-left:45%; or margin-left:auto with a margin-right:auto property on the .logo img elemsome solution in that ballpark.

/S

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css applied to logo img. Hope this works.

```
.logo img {
  width:220px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```